# How can I create a user account when a node is created?

Tags: forms

How can I show the user registration form upon node creation and create a new user when a node is submitted in Drupal 7?

I want this to be done in the Drupal way without writing any code.

Comment: please explain more... you want embed user registration form into node creation form? why you need this? create new user on node submit is another question...

Comment: Just FYI, doing things the Drupal way and doing things without writing code aren't mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) for this.

Create a new rule that has *After saving new content* as the Event and then set any conditions that you have (node type etc).

Then in the actions section, add a *Create new entity* condition with the value of *User*

From the next page you set the e-mail address and username of the user account, so you'll probably want to have these as fields on your node type.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to have the ability to utilize Rules for this.

Make another Rule that has After saving new content as the Event and after that set any conditions that you have.

At that point in the actions area, include a Create new entity condition with the value of User

In the next page you set the email address and username of the client account, so you'll likely need to have these as fields on your node type.

Comment: Wow you beated me to time!