# Anonymous Usernames

Tags: forms, users

Good day to you!

I want to let anonymous users create content on website. But when I allow them create some node type, I noticed that they cannot specify their username. I can add new field for username, but this is bad for Views and I think this is not correct. Probably I need to change their username after form submission from Anonymous to specified in fake username form.

How you would made this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Adding a field seems like the perfect solution to what you've described, could you explain a bit more about why you think that would be bad for Views? Content is linked to a user (in this case user 0, anonymous) for the author property, so if not fields you'd need a custom solution that stored usernames against the database manually on node add/update. By which point you probably might as well have used a field

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am creating small forum for anonymous users. I checked Forum and Advanced Forum modules, but they too complicated for my website. So, I add new content type — Topic, add View named Forum with field Last Answer, that get username from Last Comment or Topic. If I add custom field, I don't know how I can create view rule for both Topic and Comment.

Comment: * from Last Comment or Topic if there is 0 comments *

Comment: The following question & answers may be helpful: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29436/

Comment: Thank you! On link that you wrote I found nice idea — to create a new user on node creation and user Rules after this. But it also look not easy: if I think correct, on node creation I need to check if this user exists, then get it uid, or if user is not exists I need to create a user and get his id before node creation. Is Rules enough powerful for this? I will check it, but I get new idea: what if I made custom filter for views, is this possible? Possible without programming? Something like this: if node have comments than show last comment author field, else show fake username field.